# How to create splats from points with normals in three.js?

Tags: three.js, points

I am a newbie in both OpenGL as well as Three.js, I am working on a streaming based "on-line" viewer which uses websockets to transmit points (with surface normals) from one system application to a remote web interface. Long story short, I have modified [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_buffergeometry_points) and use THREE.PointsMaterial to visualize incoming data with points.

Since I already am sending points locations [xyz], color [rgb] and normals [abc] so I would love to use technique such as surface-splatting [Splatting](https://cgl.ethz.ch/research/past_projects/surfels/surfacesplatting/index.html). Unfortunately due to my limited knowledge and lack of internet resources can any one guide me to implement a very basic surface splatting technique using three.js?

**Question: How to draw elliptical surfaces instead of points in three.js**

Any help will be highly appreciated.[image: point_viewer]

Comment: [Many of the samples using points on the three.js site use circle textures](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=bill#webgl_points_billboards). Change them into elipses?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I already saw that example. care to hint me how to use circle texture with normals?

Answer (score 1):

it would probably work using points if you compute the point-size per point such that the whole ellipsis fits in there and use the fragment-shader to compute the area of the ellipsis based on the viewing-angle (i suppose this is what you want to do, right?).

Alternatively, you can use instancing based on a simple quad and use instance-attributes for position and orientation of the quads. In this case, you just need to render a circle into each of the quads.

Comment: Hi Martin, since I have some basic (theoratical) idea of splatting and I do not want anything fancy (such as EWA, blending or variable size ellipses). For starter, I will assume all ellipses will have same size. It will look very ugly, but got to start somewhere.